# How can I Write on 64bit registry?

Tags: vb.net

Well, I want to create a registry key on

"HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\WINLOGON\" and I have this code:

```
    Sub RegKeySave(ByVal i_RegKey As String,
           ByVal i_Value As String,
  Optional i_Type As String = "REG_SZ")
    Dim myWS As Object

    'access Windows scripting
    myWS = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
    'write registry key
    myWS.RegWrite(i_RegKey, i_Value, i_Type)

End Sub
```

The Problem this create on HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\WINLOGON. Can someone help me.

Comment: Please see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cy6azwf7.aspx

Comment: @VirtualAnomaly I have already readed that link and it does the same thing above.

Comment: @VisualVincent Thank you problem solved

Comment: No problem. You should accept this as a duplicate then, so that it'll be closed.